# My Deployed Site Column Lookup Isn't Referencing the List

Tags: list, lookup-column, site-column

I have a SharePoint list that was created through the SharePoint UI (i.e. not through code/features/packages). I'm trying to define a site column in my feature/package that is a lookup to this table.

Here's some details about the existing list:

- **Path**: Lists/ProductCodeData
- **EntityTypeName**: ProductCodeDataList
- **Title**: Product Code Data

Here's my attempt at a Site Column definition that references the product list as a lookup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">  
  <Field
       ID="{a826a885-f58b-4f3d-91cf-6d107b8dbf19}"
       StaticName="ProductCodeTest"
       Name="ProductCodeTest"
       DisplayName="Product Code"
       Type="Lookup"
       Required="TRUE"
       EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE"
       List="Lists/ProductCodeData"
       Group="Custom Columns">
  </Field>
</Elements>
```

After I deploy the site column and view it through the UI, it seems that the Site Column is unable to resolve the list lookup.

[image]

For the Site Column definition, I've tried using the EntityTypeName, Title, and path as the List property, none of which have worked. I can't use the GUID/ID of the list for cross-environment deployment reasons.

How can I get this site column to properly lookup the product list?

*SharePoint 2013 On-premise*

Comment: try to add the attribute `ShowField="Title"` to the field definition

Comment: @NkSP I gave that a shot, but it didn't fix the issue. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: Are you sure the url in the `List` attribute is spelled correctly? Also as @NkSP mentioned, include the `ShowField` attribute.